# Refresh Index after redirecting to it from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a situation where I am setting a user value and trying to reload the index page.  This is only a sample page and I cannot user any kind of user controls, like ASP.NET.  Each user is in the database and the role is retrieved from there.  My index is this:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(long? id)
    {
        AdminModel admin = new AdminModel();
        UserModel usermodel = new UserModel();
        if (id != null)
        {
            admin.UserModel = usermodel;
            admin.UserModel.UserId = id.ToString();
            admin.UserModel = UserAndRoleRepository.GetOrStoreUserProfile(admin.UserModel.UserId);
        }
        else
        {
            admin.UserModel = usermodel;
            admin.UserModel = UserAndRoleRepository.GetOrStoreUserProfile(currentUser);
        }

        return View(admin);
    }
```

This works fine when first loaded.  In the page I am setting values based upon the user role:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    user = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
    if (user.UserModel != null) {
        if (user.UserModel.UserRole == 'ADMIN') {
            $("#btnAdmin").show();
            $("#btnTran").show();
            $("#btnNew").show();
            $("#btnAdjust").show();
            $("#btnReports").show();
        }
        if (user.UserModel.UserRole == 'TRANS') {
            $("#btnReports").show();
            $("#btnTran").show();
        }
        if (user.UserModel.UserRole == 'REPORTS') {
            $("#btnReports").show();
        }
    }
   });
```

The AJAX call is this:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("SetUser")',
                data: { userid: ui.item.value },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == null) {

                    }
                    else {

                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    //var err = xhr.responseText;
                    //alert('error');
                }
            });
```

And the SetUser action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetUser(string userid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = Convert.ToInt64(userid) });
    }
```

This works fine in that the Index method is fired with the chosen ID, but the page does not reload to be able to set the buttons.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's beacuse you have an ajax call. In the ajax success method, do `location.reload(true)` - [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: The reload simply loads my Index again with me as the user, since the ID is not passed to the index.

Comment: @Dean.DePue did you find solution, or you still need help?

Comment: Had to leave work - will post what I did tomorrow that works for my unique situation...

Comment: @Dean.DePue any resolution? Did answers below help you or you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

It won't redirect because you're returning an action via an ajax call. The best thing to do here would be to return the `userid` as JSON, then do the redirect.

So the ajax `success` function would be:

```
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null && data.UserID != null) {
                    location.href = '@(Url.Action("SetUser"))?userid=' + data.UserID;
                }
                else {
                    location.reload(); //something went wrong?
                }
            },
        });
```

And your action would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SetUser(string userid)
{
    return Json(new { UserID = Convert.ToInt64(userid) });
}
```

Comment: This does not work, it simply reloads the page with the same user id, mine.  It should call the index method again with the new ID and then reload the page to be able to set the buttons.

Comment: have you tried this? - location.href = '@Url.Action("SetUser",new { userid=" + data.UserID +" }' ;

Comment: @Dean.DePue It's the same process outlined in your example code. The idea behind my code is that within the `HttpPost` method you send the user ID, it then navigates to the same page, but with the new user ID in the query string (which invokes the index method with the new user ID). Is that not what you want?

Comment: @AdershM That won't work, you can't mix JavaScript and Razor interchangably like that because Razor is evaluated on the server, the JavaScript is evaluated on the client.

Comment: In my opinion, razor codes do work in javascript and I had tried this. When the page runs, the Url.Action methods expands to a valid url link like /Contoller/Action?userid = 123. the porblem may be with the query string

Comment: @AdershM That code you posted won't work, try it :).

Comment: forgot to mention, the above code only works when it is in the same cshtml file. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to make Ajax POST call? If not you can replace that code with

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index")' + '/' + ui.item.value
```

or

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index")' + '?id=' + ui.item.value
```

depending on your route mapping.